# Next-auth, MongoDB and AWS SES not working properly

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, next.js, nodemailer, next-auth

I want to use next-auth with the email provider (passwordless signin) for a login page, and use MongoDB to store a new user etc. As for the email sending I would like to use AWS SES.

Current status:
I have implemented a boilerplate next app with create-next-app and installed mongodb, next-auth and the email-provider. I have added a lib/mongodb.js file to connect to my database and a [...nextauth.js] file to setup the next-auth functionalities. I have added the email provider and also setup AWS SES with 2 verified identities.

lib/mongodb.js

```
// This approach is taken from https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-mongodb
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';

const uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
const options = {
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useNewUrlParser: true,
};

let client;
let clientPromise;

if (!process.env.MONGODB_URI) {
  throw new Error('Please add your Mongo URI to .env.local');
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  if (!global._mongoClientPromise) {
    client = new MongoClient(uri, options);
    global._mongoClientPromise = client.connect();
  }
  clientPromise = global._mongoClientPromise;
} else {
  client = new MongoClient(uri, options);
  clientPromise = client.connect();
}

export default clientPromise;
```

[...nextauth.js]

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import { MongoDBAdapter } from '@next-auth/mongodb-adapter';
import EmailProvider from 'next-auth/providers/email';
import clientPromise from '../../../lib/mongodb';

const THIRTY_DAYS = 30 * 24 * 60 * 60;
const THIRTY_MINUTES = 30 * 60;

export default NextAuth({
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
  session: {
    strategy: 'jwt',
    maxAge: THIRTY_DAYS,
    updateAge: THIRTY_MINUTES,
  },
  adapter: MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise),
  providers: [
    EmailProvider({
      server: {
        host: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_HOST,
        port: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_PORT,
        auth: {
          user: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_USER,
          pass: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_PASSWORD,
        },
      },
      from: process.env.EMAIL_FROM,
    }),
  ],
});
```

Problem:
When I npm run dev my project and go to the default sigin path, the e-mail login form is shown as expected. But when I enter an email address and click on "signin with email" nothing happens. I see a connection in my MongoDB Atlas database, but nothing is created and no email gets sent. The page reloads and the network tab in the dev-tools shows a 302 redirection.

[image]

I would just like to know which parts dont work, since no error gets thrown and I am not experienced at all. Most tutorials or code snippets either use oauth, as postgres db or prisma. But since I am using mongodb and no oauth it is hard to find a lot of sourcecode and explanations.

I wondered:
AWS SES seems to work fine on its own, I sent an email from the AWS console, do I need to do more than reference my SMTP credentials in an .env file and import them like that? For example setup nodemailer? It was mentioned in the next-auth docs but not as obligatory and its own documenation says its not necessarily needed for simple email sendings with SES.

Sould I try a different email sending tool, like sendgrid?
Should I try a different db?

Most mistakes I made so far in programming were pretty damn stupid, so I would also not be surprised if I am overlooking something obvious here. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I couldn't get AWS SES configured as you have it.  I had to provide a single connect string for AWS.

This did not work

```
    EmailProvider({
      server: {
        host: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_HOST,
        port: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_PORT,
        auth: {
          user: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_USER,
          pass: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_PASSWORD,
        },
      },
      from: process.env.EMAIL_FROM,
    }),
```

This did

```
    EmailProvider({
      server: `smtp://${process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_USER}:${process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_PASSWORD}@${process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_HOST}`,
      from: process.env.EMAIL_FROM,
    }),
```

If I included the port (25) in that connect string it would fail to connect.